# Question of the Week #34

Tags: discussion, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into week 34 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity's sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest). If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we'll to try to post about a question and its contents.

When submitting a QotW, please indicate if you would be interested in writing about it for the blog. This is a factor which we take into consideration when selecting what to blog about - we need a post we can actually say something interesting about; it shouldn't be something we've written about too much before, and it helps to have somebody interested in writing the article.

Comment: We really need to make this more prominent.

Comment: Agreed @slhck. Any ideas? We have a community promotion ad but that doesn't seem to bring in much voting.

Comment: What does it take to get up a status bar (like the one used for planned maintenance or elections), linking to a post where we explain that the blog needs help? For example, with regards to new authors, topic ideas, regular writers, etc.

Comment: @slhck about 3 clicks, but I don't know that it would be an appropriate use of the system-wide notification feature. Might make more sense to write a blog post about it, actually.

Comment: Hm. Who gets to decide if it's appropriate? Of course writing a blog post would be a start.

Comment: @slhck site moderators can choose to post one at their discretion, but Jeff has made it clear that they should be used for very rare circumstances only. I would start a new meta post about it at the very least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Does "Stopping" USB drives actually affect the drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/357815/does-stopping-usb-drives-actually-affect-the-drive)

A great answer with a little-known option of how Windows handles external drives.

Comment: I would be willing to write about this...

Comment: Thanks @BillyONeal. I'll contact you with info about how to get a post up on the blog shortly, probably sometime tomorrow.

Comment: Hey @BillyONeal... sorry for the delay, I was busy with school and turkey consumption. I created an account for you on our blog, so whenever you have time to write about this, go for it. If you have any questions, drop by chat.

Comment: Not a problem. :) I'll look soon. And that password is meme-tastic :P

Comment: @BillyONeal you'd better change it!

Comment: Lol... I did :)

Comment: @BillyONeal any progress on a post? Wondering when we should schedule it in. Doesn't have to be long - just a couple paragraphs summarizing the question and answer will suffice! Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: It's on my todo list for this weekend. Sorry, this being finals week my time has been limited. Hope you are well :)

Comment: I completely understand - all my finals are next week, so I'm feeling the crunch too. Just wanted to check in on the status of things. Good luck on your exams; I'm looking forward to your post later!

Answer (score 0):

I think we must be in week 34 now, however here is my candidate.

The answer is mine, but I haven't seen this question asked or the technique supplied before.

[How can I prove (with logging) where a port block is occurring?](https://superuser.com/questions/358348/how-can-i-prove-with-logging-where-a-port-block-is-occurring)